# View function did not return a response in flask

Tags: python, cookies, flask-login, valueerror

I have a code below which setups cookie and then adds this cookie to the response with `set_cookies` function. However, even though I return a response I received the following error:

`ValueError: View function did not return a response`

My code is simply this:

```
def login():

 if request.method == "POST":
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    cookie = timestamp+'user'
    cookie = base64.b64encode(cookie.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    resp = make_response()
    resp = resp.set_cookie("LoginCookie",cookie)
    return resp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response.set_cookie is an [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) operation. This means that if you set something to it's return value, it will be None, which is the default return value (functions with no return return None).
What should be used instead is:

```
resp.set_cookie("LoginCookie",cookie)
```